# How to get colored legend with seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

There is a problem with `plt.legend` in seaborn and matplotlib. What is wrong with it?
I can't see the legend color.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))
plt.xticks(rotation='85')
sns.barplot(x='label',y='cnt',data=group_label)
plt.legend(group_label['class'].unique())
```

[image: The output I am getting]

[image: My data]

[image: to 'tdy', working well!]

Comment: Well, to get other people to test your problem, you need to provide code in your question.

Comment: Matplotlib's `plt.legend` often doesn't work well with seaborn plots.  Seaborn plots create their own legends.  To change position or other legend properties, since seaborn 11.2 you can use `sns.move_legend(...)`. Also see [this issue as github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2231) . Which seaborn version are you using?

Comment: im sorry i'm forgot to provide my code,

Comment: i have check my searborn version, and it is <1.1.5>.

seaborn automatically make color with grouped ['class']  but i cant make them legend

Comment: remove the `plt.legend` line and just use seaborn's `hue` parameter: `sns.barplot(x='label', y='cnt', hue='class', data=group_label)`

Comment: also need the `dodge` parameter. i'll post an answer in a sec for more details

Comment: yesterday i did this code without dodge... wow it's not legend problem. thank you to solve my problem!  I hope you have a happy weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using matplotlib's `plt.legend`, just use seaborn's `hue` parameter. Also, in your case you want each bar to take the full width, so disable the `dodge` behavior as well:

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x='label', y='cnt', hue='class', dodge=False)
#                                        ---          -----
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# random data
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': np.random.choice(['bottle', 'cable', 'leather', 'pill', 'zipper'], size=n), 'cnt': np.random.randint(80, size=n)}).sort_values('class')
df['label'] = df['class'] + df.index.astype(str)

# barplot using hue and dodge
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
sns.barplot(data=df, x='label', y='cnt', hue='class', dodge=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image: output]